# only show certain amount of years in dropdown to ensure the user is 18

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a year dropdown on my form, the user will come along and enter their data of birth.

What I'm trying to achieve is within the component workout how many years I should display that would make sure the person is of age 18 +.

So far I have this, I first deduct 18 years from todays date which brings me to 1999 so I know the user is 18.

```
getYears() {

    var ageRestriction: number = 18;
    var now = new Date();
    var thisDate = (now.getFullYear() - 18);

   // now show the previous dates i.e 1999, 1998, 1997, 1997 etc

}
```

I then need to loop through and show 60 years before 1999 so

1999,
1998,
1997,
1996,
1995,
1994
etc etc

I can't for the life of me figure out how the syntax would be for this hence this question.

Can someone show me how I go about doing this? or if someone knows of a better way of doing this then feel free to educate me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the approach I would take.

```
years: number[] = [];
setYears() {
    const ageRestriction = 18;
    const now = new Date();
    const maxYear = (now.getFullYear() - ageRestriction);
    const minYear = (maxYear - 61);

    for (let i = maxYear; i >= minYear; i--) {
        this.years.push(i);
    }
}
```

I suppose there could be a more elegant way, but this does the trick. I assumed you wanted this sorted descending (most recent year first, or at the top of the list).

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Does exactly what I'm looking for, thanks for your help.